# jQuery Mask plugin multiple masks for phone number on the same element doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mask

I am using the jQuery Mask plugin and I used it before tons of times but now I have to do it for production release, I can't seem to mask a phone number input correctly, I can input `(11) 1111-1111` without problem but it doesn't let me add another number, if I did add another number it should change the mask to `(11) 1 1111-1111`. That is the same example found on every website (including this one).

```js
$().ready(() => {
  var moptions = {
    placeholder: "(__) ____-____",
    onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options) {
      var masks = ["(00) 0000-0000", "(00) 0 0000-0000"];
      var mask = cep.length > 14 ? masks[1] : masks[0];
      $(".phone").mask(mask, options);
    }
  };

  $(".phone").mask("(00) 0000-0000", moptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="phone"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue here is that you are attempting to detect the length of the string, however when you switch masks you are introducing two additional characters `'0 '`, which is throwing off the number of characters to use.

You might consider ignoring non-digit characters which would give you a better idea of which mask to use such that the masks wouldn't interfere with your count using an example like the following:

```js
$().ready(() => {
  var maskOptions = {
    placeholder: "(__) ____-____",
    onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options) {
      // Use an optional digit (9) at the end to trigger the change
      var masks = ["(00) 0000-00009", "(00) 0 0000-0000"],
        digits = cep.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").length,
        // When you receive a value for the optional parameter, then you need to swap
        // to the new format
        mask = digits <= 10 ? masks[0] : masks[1];

      $(".phone").mask(mask, options);
    }
  };

  $(".phone").mask("(00) 0000-0000", maskOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="phone" />
```

Comment: Thank you, also had no idea 9 meant optional, I was using it instead of 0 on everything.

Comment: Yup, that’s the default for digits. It’s worth noting you can also [define your own translations](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#translation) as well if you wanted to use something different or needed more advanced masking support.